# Format the output from paste function to include NULL where values are missing

Tags: r, paste, rodbc

I have a dataset with three columns (a, b, c).

```
  a   b  c
  ----------------- 
  63  0        
  78  0        
  79  0        
  10  0        
  11  0        
  12  0        
  13  0       
  16  0        
  16  0        
  16  1  2014-04-24
```

I am trying to insert the values from these columns into an SQL table from R.

I am using the paste function to pass the values from the dataset into the SQL statement.

```
valuestest1 <- paste("(",df$a,",",df$b,",",df$c,")", sep="", collapse=",")
valuestest1
```

The output I get from this paste function is as follows:

```
"(63,0,),(78,0,),(79,0,),(10,0,),(11,0,),(12,0,),(13,0,),(16,0,),(16,0,),(16,1,2014-04-24)"
```

This doesn't work with the insert statement, because after a lot of trial and error, I found that:

1) I need to insert NULL where values are missing as follows:

```
      "(63,0,NULL),(78,0,NULL),(79,0,NULL),(10,0,NULL),(11,0,NULL),(12,0,NULL),(13,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,1,2014-04-24)"
```

2) I should enclose the date value with a single quote, as in  '2014-04-24'

```
       "(63,0,NULL),(78,0,NULL),(79,0,NULL),(10,0,NULL),(11,0,NULL),(12,0,NULL),(13,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,1,'2014-04-24')"
```

Right now, I don't know how to format this paste function to produce such an output.

So I need help. Thanks folks, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your data and it is formatted correctly, you would have this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(63, 78, 79, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 16, 16), b=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), c=c("","","","","","","","","","2014-04-24"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)       

> df
    a b          c
1  63 0           
2  78 0           
3  79 0           
4  10 0           
5  11 0           
6  12 0           
7  13 0           
8  16 0           
9  16 0           
10 16 1 2014-04-24
```

Go ahead and put your quotes around everything in the 3rd column:

```
df[,3] <- paste("'", df[, 3], "'", sep="")
```

...and get:

```
> df
    a b            c
1  63 0           ''
2  78 0           ''
3  79 0           ''
4  10 0           ''
5  11 0           ''
6  12 0           ''
7  13 0           ''
8  16 0           ''
9  16 0           ''
10 16 1 '2014-04-24'
```

Now, deal with the quotes that are empty:

```
> df[df=="''"]<-'NULL'
```

which gives you

```
> df
    a b            c
1  63 0           NULL
2  78 0           NULL
3  79 0           NULL
4  10 0           NULL
5  11 0           NULL
6  12 0           NULL
7  13 0           NULL
8  16 0           NULL
9  16 0           NULL
10 16 1 '2014-04-24'
```

Now you can paste like you did in the question:

```
    valuestest1 <- paste("(",df$a,",",df$b,",",df$c,")", sep="", collapse=",")
    valuestest1
[1] "(63,0,NULL),(78,0,NULL),(79,0,NULL),(10,0,NULL),(11,0,NULL),(12,0,NULL),(13,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,1,'2014-04-24')"
```

Comment: I dont want to modify the dataframe. I am aiming to accomplish this within the paste function outside the dataframe if thats possible.

Comment: Modifying the dataset could be very simple... just an extra line of code... but it depends on what you are starting with.

Answer (score 0):

We can `transform` the blank elements in 'c' column i.e. `''` to 'NULL'.  Here I used `ifelse` to do that.  We `paste` the rows together using `do.call(paste`, the arguments can be placed in a `list` (`list(sep=',')`), format the string by including `(` and `)` with `sprintf` and `collapse` it to a single string with `paste`.  We could possibly remove the `sprintf` step by pasting the `()` with the outer `paste`.

```
paste(
    sprintf('(%s)',
         do.call(paste,
              c(transform(df1, c= ifelse(c=='', 'NULL', c)),
                                 list(sep=',')))),
                                          collapse=',')
#[1] "(63,0,NULL),(78,0,NULL),(79,0,NULL),(10,0,NULL),(11,0,NULL),(12,0,NULL),(13,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,1,2014-04-24)"
```

If we need single quotes for `'2014-04-24'`, we can change the `ifelse` statement to format the 'Date' using `sprintf`.

```
 paste(
    sprintf('(%s)',
         do.call(paste,
              c(transform(df1, c= ifelse(c=='', 'NULL', sprintf("'%s'",c))),
                                 list(sep=',')))),
                                          collapse=',')
#[1] "(63,0,NULL),(78,0,NULL),(79,0,NULL),(10,0,NULL),(11,0,NULL),(12,0,NULL),(13,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,0,NULL),(16,1,'2014-04-24')"
```

NOTE: This provides the expected result showed in the OP's post.  Also, it should work even if there are 100 columns or so i.e. we don't need to manually type in

```
 paste("(",df$a,",",df$b,",",df$c,...., df$xyz...`
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(63L, 78L, 79L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 
16L, 16L), b = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), c = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "2014-04-24")), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: for some reason I am getting an error unexpected '=' in "transform(df1, df$c="

Comment: @HeatherKeturah  Based on the example in my post, I am not getting any error

Comment: let me try again :), i might be missing something

Comment: @HeatherKeturah  I checked again, it is running fine.